# Visual Studio 2012 XAML Designer Vertical Split Can't Be Set As Default?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, xaml-designer

Is there only `Horizontal Split` as default and not `Vertical Split`? Again or my eyes are going bad? It was an issue in VS2008 and VS2010 when it was per-file basis so nothing has changed?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to split the XAML designer vertically into XAML markup and visual?

Comment: No, I'm trying to figure out if I can set the Vertical Split as default. Now when I open the new XAML file it always opens in Horizontal Split. It remembers on per-file basis that this file was closed with Vertical Split so next time it's opened as Vertical Split. But when I add another new file it's opened in Horizontal Split again.

Answer (score 1):

Yep there is currently no way of defaulting to a vertical split for the XAML designer in VS2012.

Like you mentioned the only way at this point is doing it per-file basis as these settings are saved together in your .suo file.

This applies to VS08 and VS10 or VS12...

If you do want to let microsoft know that you would like this to be a feature you can send them a request [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio)

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1bdf2ddd-472c-4c17-ad2e-845f5bf1f086/default-designer-to-vertical-split-view?forum=vswpfdesigner) is the original thread about this issue.

Its funny though that their HTML designer does allow [defaulting to vertical split](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/30/enabling-vertical-split-view-in-vs-2008.aspx)..